# List hidden files without using - ( * |

Tags: command-line, bash, ls, hidden-files

Is it possible to list hidden files without using the characters mentioned above? This means not using any options or the * wildcard as well as some other characters (e.g this is **not** allowed `ls -a`, `ls -d`, `.!(|.)`, `echo .*` etc.).

Comment: May I ask... why?

Comment: Part of a homework. ? and + are allowed. Any other suggestions? This did not work, tried everything possible on the internet. Need something that works in general.

Comment: I'd be careful then... `la` is not present in all linuxes.

Comment: Do you want to list all files *including* hidden ones, or *only* hidden ones?

Comment: I need the hidden ones, it does not matter if it will display others or not.

Comment: @IvayloToskov which version of Ubuntu are you running? It seems like you don't run an Ubuntu machine. Questions about linux distributions other than Ubuntu are asked [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @IvayloToskov Please update the question when you discover another limitation instead of scattering the information around in comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`find .` will list all files including hidden ones.

Corollary: Somebody thinks it's a good idea to [teach about command injection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486534/list-hidden-files-without-using#comment649439_486539) by blacklisting individual characters and [possibly even commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486534/list-hidden-files-without-using#comment649432_486537) in your script. That is actively harmful to your learning about the shell because you end up with hacks like [escape characters](https://askubuntu.com/a/486551/10371) or [relying on Ubuntu-specific default configuration](https://askubuntu.com/a/486536/10371), both of which won't be able to [handle special file names](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/examples/safe-find.sh).

It actually sounds like whoever came up with this wanted to use `eval` for some reason (which is always* a terrible idea) rather than just executing the submitted code or script directly.

The absolutely simplest way to loop over hidden files is

```
for file in .*
do
    my_command "$file"
done
```

* Or so damn close to always that you'd better have read and understood the entire [Bash wiki article about it](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) before even considering using it.

Comment: The command could not be executed cause it is executed within another program, which for some reason restricts it.

Comment: You must be running in an extremely restricted environment if `find` isn't even available. If this is part of the task then you should specify it in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu has a default alias for `ls -la`. You can simply use

```
la
```

Comment: No aliases on the computer I am working on, including la and ll

Comment: The answer is valid and correct for Ubuntu. Are you using something else? If so...

Comment: `.bashrc` is a personnal file. I, for instance, don't have `la` in my .bashrc

Comment: @Rinzwind The question was posted on Ask Ubuntu, so I can assume that OP's using Ubuntu. Otherwise, the question is off-topic.

Comment: @enedil hence why I asked; I seriously doubt he is.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo `printf '.\x2A'`
```

Unicode table for the win.

Answer (score 1):

`echo .`<TAB><TAB>

It's already built into bash to do this.  Don't even need to execute a command.

`echo .`<Meta-*>

If you absolutely must have a command (but you still don't need any external processes.)

Comment: It isn't said that OP is using Bash.

Comment: It isn't said that OP isn't using `bash`.  Also, the question is tagged `bash`.